# 301 redirect not working

Tags: .htaccess

I have this in my .htaccess on a linux server in the root but it wont redirect my site (its a new .co domain)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mmyoldsite\au.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.co/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I think your syntax is correct and it should be working. By the way, do you have mod_rewrite enabled on your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mmyoldsite\.au\.com$ [NC]
```

Comment: Well, the site name in your original RewriteCond is wrong for the reasons steelaz corrects here, but if you've changed the site name for your example it's going to be very difficult for us to debug, isn't it? Note also you may want a leading `(www\.)?`.

Comment: Thanks bobince...i got it working adding the www\. and steelaz's comments